# Given the function,check the continuity at $(0,0)$ and find $f_x(0,0),f_y(0,0)$ if they exist

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, solution-verification, partial-derivative, epsilon-delta

Given a function defined by :
$$f(x,y) =
  \begin{cases}
                                   \frac{x^{3}+y^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{2}} & (x,y) \ne (0,0) \\
  0 & (x,y) = (0,0)
  \end{cases}$$

Find $f_x(0,0),f_y(0,0)$ is they exist ,is the function continuous at $(0,0)$?

---

$f_x(0,0)$ and $f_y(0,0)$ exist if the following limits exist (respectively):

$$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{f\left(\Delta x,0\right)-f\left(0,0\right)}{ \Delta x}=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{\Delta x-0}{\Delta x}=1$$
$$\lim_{\Delta y \to 0}\frac{f\left(0,\Delta y\right)-f\left(0,0\right)}{ \Delta y}=\lim_{\Delta y \to 0}\frac{\Delta y-0}{\Delta y}=1$$

So $f_x(0,0) =1=f_y(0,0)$

About the continuity of the function at the given point we have that $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^{3}+y^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}=0$$

Because for $\left|x\right|,\left|y\right|<\delta$ :

$$\left|\frac{x^{3}+y^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}-0\right|\le\frac{\left|x\right|^{3}+\left|y\right|^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}=\frac{\left(\left|x\right|+\left|y\right|\right)\left(x^{2}-\left|xy\right|+y^{2}\right)}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\le\frac{\left(\left|x\right|+\left|y\right|\right)\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$$$$=\left|x\right|+\left|y\right|<2\delta$$

So taking $\delta \le \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ proves the claim.

---

I would like to know if my solution is true or not,and see the errors (if exists),so if you have an alternative solution then please **first** check mine and then provides yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is fine. For the continuity of $f$ in $(0,0)$ you can use polar coordinates:

With $x= r \cos t$ and $y=r \sin t$ you get

$$|f(x,y)-0| \le r (| \cos t|+ |\sin t|) \le 2r=2 \sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$$